# How to make CTRL-D/EOF in Mac Terminal quit the terminal (as in CMD+Q) if active window is the only one

Tags: macos, terminal

I have this function in my ~/.bash_profile file

```
function exit {
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit if not ((count windows) > 1) then quit'
}
```

How can I map this kind of functionality to the CTRL-D/EOF inside Terminal, so I wont have to write exit?

Using EOF only closes the terminal window and not the application itself.